# Transient analysis of op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transient

What is the expression of V if V(0) = 4V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZQSPC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am unable to proceed further after forming the following equation:
*-v/R1=(v-V)/R2+C1dv/dt*

Comment: Instead of slapping some formulas on the circuit, do you understand what will happen? First assume C1 isn't there, what are the voltages and currents? Then I connect C1 and it is charged to 4 V, what happens now?

Comment: Like @Bimpelrekkie says then apply a step on the output, so you get dv/dt feedback inverted so the result is an integrator.  in+ - Vin- =0

Comment: Overload recovery of an opamp is a piece-wise function and best left to a spice simulator. At $$t = 0+\eps\$$ the opamp's output will slew and then hit the negative rail...

Answer (score 1):

Let the op amp output voltage be \$v_o\$

At the inverting input, \$v^-=0\$ since it's a virtual earth.

Therefore, KCL at the \$ v^-\$ node gives:

$$ C\frac{dv_o}{dt}+\frac{v_o}{R_2}=0$$
or
$$ \frac{dv_o}{dt}+\frac{v_o}{R_2C}=0$$

Solving this ODE:

$$ v_o=Ae^{-t/R_2C}$$

Initial condition: $$ t=0,\: v_o=4$$

Hence \$A=4\$, and:

$$ v_o=4e^{-t/R_2C}=4e^{-2t}$$

Answer (score -1):

If the op-amp output is 4 volts (and stable at that value) then, because an op-amp has a massive open-loop gain, the differential voltage between the  inverting and non-inverting inputs must be close to zero volts i.e. in the realm of 1 mV. Given that the non-inverting input is connected to 0 volts, the inverting input is probably within a milli volt or so of 0 volts.

This means that one side of the capacitor is at 4 volts (because it connects to the output) and the other side is around +/- 1 mV away from 0 volts.

In an ideal op-amp the gain is infinite and there are no input errors so Vc = Vo.

It's got nothing to do with R1 or R2 theoretically.

Comment: Ah a down vote.... any comment to explain why?